# Customize the labels of X axis [core-plot]

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm working with core-plot and having problem with the x axis' customization .
I want x axis' labels to display some dates but they don't have an equal difference . For example , the dates may be like this : 2012-05-06 , 2012-06-08 , 2012-07-21 ... So I think I can not set the axis labels by setting the major interval . Can anyone tell me the way to do this ? Any suggestion will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,If those dates are consecutive value means You can achieve this while creating a custom label.  You can add your consecutive dates into an Array and set this array to `majorTickLocations` property of your X axis. 
 following line add into your custom label generation method. customStick is value u wanted to set.
`[customTick addObject:customStick];`

add this line in your axis property set.
`axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLocations    = [NSSet setWithArray:customTick];`

Comment: Don't forget to use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided` labeling policy, too.

Comment: I still have a question . Do I need to set the majorTickLength , minorTickLength and labelOffset of the X axis ?

Comment: Not Necessary at all, thats depends upon our need. If u need labelOffset, you should define while generating custom label.